# Transfer files using C++ between computers

Tags: c++, sockets, socket.io

I am simply trying to send files from 1 computer to another using C++. I am only interacting with 1 client but the code is still not working.

```
void runclient(char *ip, char *fpath)
{
char rec[32] = "";
a.connectServer(ip,IPaddress);
printf("Connected to server \n");
a.sendData("FileSend"); a.recvData(rec,32);
a.fileSend(fpath);
printf("Sent\n");
a.sendData("EndConnection");a.recvData(rec,32);
printf("Connection ended \n");
}
```

Any ideas on how to easily send files using C++??
I need to use C++ as I will be using it for real-time applications in the future.

Comment: I am just trying to transfer files for now. I will get into sockets once I am done with this part.

Comment: Can you clarify the framework you're trying to use? It's not clear from the example what libraries etc you are using. Sockets is generally the basic way of getting data from one place to another, but if you're using something else then you need to show a working example of what you're using.

Comment: What is `a`? Are you using a library or is `a` some instance of a class you've made yourself?

Comment: To transfer a file you need sockets. That is the way to send things over a network. It does not matter if you are sending a file or something else, sockets are what you will be using. Of course., There are libraries that wrap sockets around some levels of indirection. But they are the lowest layer. What do you mean by "I will get into sockets once I am done with this part"?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using sockets there is no simple way of doing that. You will have to write some form of communication protocol to organize the stream of information between the two peers.

A couple things you are already doing wrong:

1. You don't check if connection was successful.
2. You are trying to receive data on a blocking pipe without checking if there is actually data to be read. This will hang your program until something is received.
3. You don't care what your peer is saying.
4. You don't care about the size of the message. TCP is a stream, not standalone packets, data from multiple send requests can be merged while reading, you have to manage that.
5. You don't tell your peer what's the file name is, I'm pretty sure it's supposed to know that.

Also, you have to clarify your question, what type of object is `a` anyway? And does it really have to be a global object? Because that's really bad practice.

Comment: I have declared a as WComm a. I am only sending data through the program. As no data is received we should probably not have a hanging problem.

Comment: (1) No evidence for this: `connectServer()` could have thrown an exception. (2) Nothing wrong with this: that's how it is normally done. (3) No evidence for this, as he hasn't provided `recvData()`. (4) No evidence for this either, as he hasn't provided `fileSend()`.

Comment: @EJP You're presuming a lot there. He is probably just a newbie trying to make this work: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5e351750-7132-41a4-b439-d5e41265a5fc/winsock-filename-gets-the-same-with-content?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: A program can hang anywhere. Never assume something will work right always. Even sending data you could have an exception that would prevent further progress.